# What does "Seeding to 3 of 4 connected peers 7kB/s ▲" mean?

Tags: transmission

This is Transmission BitTorrent Client:

[image]

What does the "Seeding to 3 of 4 connected peers 7kB/s ▲"?

What is seeding and what are peers? And why does this only appear after it has downloaded? Before it says "Downloading from 60 of 60 peers - 785 kB/s ▼"

Comment: Take a look at http://tech-supports.blogspot.com/2009/01/difference-between-seeders-peers-and.html

Comment: @Mitch thanks! I'm going to self answer but I was waiting for a better answer. I don't think I'm gonna get that, but feel free to post that + contents  as an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some torrent terminology:

- Peer: A user who is participating in the torrent.
- Seeder: A peer who keeps the torrent available for uploading. They can be the people who initially uploaded the torrent or those who have finished downloading it and kept it alive.
- Seeding: To keep a torrent alive for uploading once you have finished downloading (either the bits you want or the complete torrent).

Usually, *peer* just means a peer who isn't a seeder. 
In this case, you are seeding. You have a target Upload/Download ratio of 2.0 on both torrents. Once you have uploaded twice as much as you downloaded for the torrent, the application will cease seeding that torrent.

Answer (score 1):

**Seeders** are the peers who have completed downloading the file 100%

A seed is a peer that has a complete copy of the torrent’s contents and keeps uploading it.  That can be done by leaving the task running after completing the download.  The more seeders there are, the better the chances of getting a higher download speed.

**Peers** are people who are downloading the file off the seeders, they also upload a parts of the file too.

Running torrent clients that transfers data to and from other clients, is called a peer. A peer does not have the complete file; only parts of it.

Sometimes peers are also called leeches, which mean downloaders.

<sup>some information courtesy of [ABIT.CDA11](http://kickass.to/blog/ABIT.CDA11/)</sup>